# SuspiciousFileOperation joined path located outside base path component

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am getting a SuspiciousFileOperation when running the following test

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import pytest

User = get_user_model()
settings.CONNECT_HOT_FOLDER = f"{settings.ROOT_DIR}\\media\\hot_folder\\"
settings.MEDIA_ROOT = f"{settings.ROOT_DIR}\\media\\"  # <-- this was the issue!!


def image_for_test():
    employee = Employee.objects.create(core_id='1000', connect_id=1, connect_username='HOPCOBROKER.Test',)
    user = User.objects.create(username="hopcobroker\\test", employee=employee,)
    receipt = Receipt.objects.create(receipt_date=now(), description="test", amount=100.0, employee=user)
    image = ReceiptImage.objects.create(image=r'test_files\breaking_image.jpg', receipt=receipt,)
    return employee, user, receipt, image


@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_convert_creates_csv_and_pdf_file(clean_up_test_files_in_hot_folder, settings):
    employee, user, receipt, image = image_for_test()
    pdf_file = f'{settings.CONNECT_HOT_FOLDER}\\{receipt.id}.pdf'
    csv_file = f'{settings.CONNECT_HOT_FOLDER}\\{receipt.id}.csv'

    convert(receipt)

    assert os.path.isfile(pdf_file)
    assert os.path.isfile(csv_file)
```

```py
class ReceiptImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/')
    receipt = models.ForeignKey(
        Receipt,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='images',
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta_data = fields.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When opening and image with the `PIL` library like below

```py
from PIL import Image
from .models import ReceiptImage
image = ReceiptImage.objects.filter(receipt=receipt)

img = Image.open(image.image)
```

I get the following error...

Error Message:

```py
base = 'C:\\code\\receipts\\media\\'
paths = ('test_files\\no_meta_data_picture.png',)
final_path = 'C:\\code\\receipts\\media\\test_files\\no_meta_data_picture.png'
base_path = 'C:\\code\\receipts\\media\\'

    def safe_join(base, *paths):
        """
        Join one or more path components to the base path component intelligently.
        Return a normalized, absolute version of the final path.

        Raise ValueError if the final path isn't located inside of the base path
        component.
        """
        final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
        base_path = abspath(base)
        # Ensure final_path starts with base_path (using normcase to ensure we
        # don't false-negative on case insensitive operating systems like Windows),
        # further, one of the following conditions must be true:
        #  a) The next character is the path separator (to prevent conditions like
        #     safe_join("/dir", "/../d"))
        #  b) The final path must be the same as the base path.
        #  c) The base path must be the most root path (meaning either "/" or "C:\\")
        if (not normcase(final_path).startswith(normcase(base_path + sep)) and
                normcase(final_path) != normcase(base_path) and
                dirname(normcase(base_path)) != normcase(base_path)):
            raise SuspiciousFileOperation(
                'The joined path ({}) is located outside of the base path '
>               'component ({})'.format(final_path, base_path))
E           django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (C:\code\receipts\media\test_files\no_meta_data_picture.png) is located outside of the base path component (C:\code\receipts\media\)
```

Error Message from above

> > django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (C:\code\receipts\media\test_files\no_meta_data_picture.png) is located outside of the base path component (C:\code\receipts\media)

...which does not make much sense to me. In the error message it tells me what the base and final paths are. The final path is in the base path.

Below is what I think is the relevant part of settings file. Looking at other solutions I've tried adding or removing a trailing `\` or `/` with no avail. I am on windows 10.

settings.py

```py
ROOT_DIR = (
    environ.Path(__file__) - 3  # (C:\code\receipts\config(3)\settings(2)\base.py(1) )
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "media")
```

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: The error message is unidentifiable, please edit your code and mention explicitly the error. Secondly, what is `image.image`??

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It spurred me to find the answer. I was looking in my production code for where I was adding a trailing `\ `. All of the other answers on SO pointed to a trailing `\ ` being the problem. I didn't check my test code... At the top I was defining my media folder with a trailing `\ `. I was looking in the wrong spot!